# Search for a value in a column and return value from the same row but different column using Python and pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

This is my initial days working with pandas and excel.

I have two problems where I am stuck.

My excel look like this:-

| Port | NaN |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | OPS |
| 2 | WTH |
| 3 | PNS |
| 4 | SSM |
| 5 | RTY |
| 6 | EWR |

I have to search for value '4' in Column1(I dont have column name so I may have to use df.iloc[:,0]).

Now, if I find the value '4' then I should output 'SSM'.

1)I am having trouble finding the value '4' not sure which function to use. I checked the type of the return object and got this.

```
column_port=df.iloc[:,0]
print(type(column_port))
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

I am not sure how to search for a element in this return type.

2)If I found the value '4' , how to output the value from different column. In this case 'SSM'.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values

Comment: Thanks @HoxhaAlban for this great article!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

```
result = df.loc[df.iloc[:,0].eq(4)]['specify the column name here']
result = df.loc[df.iloc[:,0].eq(4)].iloc[:,'specify the column index here']
```

Comment: Thanks @Nk03. It did give me better understanding and idea about the working.
I have one question:-
I have one more column to check.
`excel.loc[column_B.eq(29) and excel["COLOR"]=='CAT6 Green']`
Its giving me this error:-
`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous`

Comment: On google it says to use '&' instead of 'and'.

Comment: This worked for me!
`excel.loc[column_B.eq(29) & excel["COLOR"].eq('CAT6 Green')`